# Asp.Net Core 1.1 failed to use Jwt Token

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, jwt, jjwt

I'm trying to implement Jwt Token Auth on a Web API ASP.Net Core 1.1 project in Visual Studio 2017. I followed the tutorial from https://samueleresca.net/2016/12/developing-token-authentication-using-asp-net-core/ but when I add the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer nuget there is no app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication methods available.

Did I missed something?

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of the nuget package have you installed?  Tutorial uses 1.0, but stable is now at 1.2

Comment: using Visual Studio 2017, I get 1.1.2 for every packages. I target .Net Core 1.1

Answer (score 1):

I created a new empty project using dotnet cli:

```
dotnet new webapi --framework netcoreapi1.1
```

and it's now working fine. there must be a problem in VS2017 WebAPI template or something...

Answer (score 0):

I have a demo project base on ASP.NET Core 1.1, SQL Server and JWT, you can try it: https://github.com/wilsonwu/netcoreauth